# How is the render() method called in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I know that the project generator in libGDX finds the `render(deltatime)` method in my Game project and make it into a game loop so that it repeats itself on an average of 60 times per second. But I want to know how exactly the project generator finds the `render()` method.

Let me give you an example:

In my game, in the Main class, I declared a SecondClass with its own `render()` method using its constructor in the `create()` of the Main class. Then, I didn't have any render() method in the MainClass. When I did this, the `render()` in the SecondClass worked. However, when I created the `render()` method in the MainClass, the `render()` from the MainClass worked but not the `render()` method in the SecondClass. Does that mean that the project generator access the first `render()` it can see as the GameLoop?

Comment: oh by the way the SecondClass implemented Screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project generator isn't doing any work here, this is all handled by the source code, using dynamic dispatch (virtual functions) and basic programming logic. Reading the [source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx) is a good way to understand how things like this work.

The [`Game` base class](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9b8f20b2d0e96e53f0f2b98dc8f6131c810aae71/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.java) you inherit from in libGDX is itself an implementation of [`ApplicationListener`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9b8f20b2d0e96e53f0f2b98dc8f6131c810aae71/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener.java), which mandates the `render()` function.

The `Game` class implements `render()` by [checking to see if the game has a screen, and if it does, it calls that screen's `render()` method](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9b8f20b2d0e96e53f0f2b98dc8f6131c810aae71/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.java#L46).

If you inherit from `Game` and provide `render()` there, you override the `Game` class's render method and yours gets called *instead*. If you don't override `render`, the `Game` class's method gets called, and it forwards along a call to the `render` method of any active screen object.

This is just how [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)/virtual functions work in Java. There's no magic examination of your source code by any project generator going on to implement this.

The [generator](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/extensions/gdx-setup) is only used to generate a stub set of files that just replace your class and package names into the source code at the right points to ensure an instance of your class is created. It doesn't do much else relevant to this operation, and it's entirely unnecessary; you could write that bootstrapping code yourself quite easily if you wanted.

Comment: How do you know LibGDX so well? You seem to be knowing every ins and outs of LibGDX. Can you tell me what tutorials or books you used to learn LibGDX? I think your tips will help accelerate my learning progress

Comment: @ChanWooKim I have never even downloaded libGDX. I just look at the source code on GitHub when people ask questions about it.

Comment: So then you are just really good at java and opengl? Good enough to understand the source code just by lookin at it once?

Comment: I've never written any Java either, but I know enough to read it and understand the basic concepts.

Comment: I wish I had them skills like you. I watched a lot of Java tutorials but I am still  unable to understand the LibGDX source code properly. Maybe it is because I am still in high school and am learning programming by myself along with all the school work. Maybe I will get a lot better when I go to university and learn from professionals.

Comment: Mostly it takes practice, just keep trying to make stuff and keep trying to read stuff to understand how it works.

Comment: Yeah, I guess at the end of the day, it comes down to practice. I've heard that a lot of University students aren't able to code properly even after they had professionals teaching them because they didn't work hard enough